# Tracking folder renaming

Tags: mv

How can I track whether a folder has been renamed - user has Mac OS 12.1

Modified date reported by Os hasn’t changed, but name has

Assume Unix records somehow

Comment: I thinki t's `Change`, not `Modify` you want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The modification date/time for the parent directory will change whenever one of its members is renamed. The item itself will not change.

Consider this example. The `mkdir` and `touch` set up the parent directory `x` and target directory `y` to have a date of 1st January. We then rename the target directory `y` to `z` and note that although it hasn't changed, the parent has done so:

```
mkdir x x/y
touch -t 202201010000 x x/y

ls -ld x x/y
drwxr-xr-x 3 roaima roaima staff Jan  1 00:00 x
drwxr-xr-x 2 roaima roaima staff Jan  1 00:00 x/y

mv x/y x/z
ls -ld x x/z
drwxr-xr-x 3 roaima roaima staff Feb  4 16:19 x
drwxr-xr-x 2 roaima roaima staff Jan  1 00:00 x/z
```

(Example taken from macOS Big Sur 11.6 with apfs as the filesystem; also confirmed on Debian with ext4)